# Understand definition of group of hyperbolic motion

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation, hyperbolic-groups

The group of hyperbolic motions is defined as the subgroup of S($\mathbb{H}^{2}$) (is the symmetric group of $\mathbb{H}^{2}$) which is generated by PGL($\mathbb{R})^{+}$ (matrices with positive determinate) and z$\mapsto \frac{1}{\overline{z}}$.

In the lecture, we also had that any hyperbolic motion is an automorphism of the hyperbolic plane as incidence geometry (for example, a straight line maps back into itself).

Can someone please give me an example?

Comment: You're looking for an example of a $2\times2$ matrix with positive determinant? Just pick four numbers and put them in an array and chances are it's an invertible matrix. If the determinant is negative, multiply a row or column by $-1$. (This question seems very similar to one I commented about the same on a bit ago, but is now deleted...)

Comment: Which model of the hyperbolic plane did you see? The disc? The upper halfplane?

Comment: @Strichcoder The upper half-plane uses $PSL_2\Bbb R$ and the disc uses $PSU(1,1)$, which are conjugate via the Cayley transform (which maps between the half-plane and disc).